# Minecraft Chat Message Replacement

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a permissions plugin, and want to replace the name of a player with their rank tag. For this, I have the following code:

```
public void playerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
    Player target = e.getPlayer();

    String message = e.getMessage().replaceAll(target.getName(), colorize(rFile.getString("players." + target)) + " " + target.getName());
    e.setMessage(message);
}
```

Whenever I send a message to chat, it appears like it would normally.
What am I doing wrong here?

Additionally, I am using a config file (cFile) and a ranks.yml file (rFile).

Comment: You should use AsyncPlayerChatEvent#setFormat to format chat messages!

Comment: Did you add the `@EventHandler` annotation? Is your listener registered?

Comment: I added @eventHandler, but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make sure you include the `@EventHandler` annotation.

```
@EventHandler
public void playerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
   [...]
}
```

Next, check if the listener is registered in your `onEnable()`method.
`getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new YourListener(...), this);`

(Replace the `YourListener` with `this` in case it's your main class)

Finally, as [Luftbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5848614/luftbaum) said, use [AsyncPlayerChatEvent#setFormat](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/event/player/AsyncPlayerChatEvent.html#setFormat(java.lang.String)) within the event. 
Example Usage:

```
 e.setFormat(colorize(rFile.getString("players." + target)) + ": " + e.getMessage());
```

**Edit:**

In order to translate color codes such as '&3' to Bukkit's [ChatColor](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html) format, you can use the [ChatColor#translateAlternativeColorCodes](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html#translateAlternateColorCodes-char-java.lang.String-) method.

```
ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', stringThatContainsCodes);
```

Comment: What do I replce YourListener with? I tried Listener(), but that won't work.

Comment: Depends; is your listener in your main class? Then just write `this`. Otherwise, the name of your listener class.

Comment: This is gonna sound very dumb. How would the listener look? Is it playerChat()?

Comment: A listener in this case is your class; If your event (the chat event in this case) is in the class that also extends `JavaPlugin`, then you can just use `this`. You might have put the event into a seperate class, a listener, though. In that case you'll have to register it that way with [...] `new YourClassNameHere();`

Comment: This is what I have now: `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);`

It throws me an error: registerEvents in the type PluginManager is not applicable for the arguments (Main, Main)

Comment: Have you extended JavaPlugin? If you don't mind, a pastebin of your code would help.

Comment: replace the `new Main()` with `this` in the registerEvents method and it should work!

Comment: `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);`, right?

Comment: Thats what I have atm

Comment: I only have the error in Eclipse:
`The method registerEvents(Listener, Plugin) in the type PluginManager is not applicable for the arguments (Main, Main)`

Comment: Oh god, my bad, should've seen that. Just add `implements Listener` after your `extends` statement to your class definition.

Comment: Doesnt work yet; Look at this massive error in the console:

Comment: That's an error with your colorize method; if you want to add color to your text, use `ChatColor`. Example: `player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "This is a red message!");`

Comment: But... I want it to pull from the file and change the & symbols to § symbols. That's the whole reason I've made the Colorize function...

Comment: Yeah, but that's a pretty unreliable way to do colouring; you can still translate the codes to chatcolor though, there's a function for that task.

Comment: I updated my post; might be more helpful for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Use`event.setFormat(playerRank + ": " + event.getMessage());`

This basically formats the message to be the way you want. You can use ChatColor to do colors. Also make sure you have @EventHandler.